# Как привязать БД к телеграм боту python

Tags: python, telegram

Захотел написать телеграмм бота для записи сообщений пользователя в БД.
Так вот набросал код но надо еще добавить запись в БД.
Вот код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Привет {message.from_user.first_name}! \n Если хочешь что то записать в базу данных пожалуйста введи /add',
                     parse_mode='html')
    print(message)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def add(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     f'Сори но я пока не придумал как записать данные в БД',
                     parse_mode='html')
    print(message)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Прежде чем добавлять запись в бд - ее нужно создать. Потом, чтобы создать бд нужно сначала выбрать какую бд вы будете использовать. Их как бы не один десяток.

Comment: И как бы токен от тг очень к месту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Шаг 1: Создаем базу данных и подключаем её к коду.

Если желаете файликом: используем библиотеку `sqlite3` [(Guide)](https://python-scripts.com/sqlite)
Если хотите использовать базу из интернета используем `mysql.connector`[(Guide)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

### Шаг 2: Пишем запросы

По ходу изучения материала выше узнаете как делать запросы в базу.
Вот пример создания записи с использованием данных из телеграмма:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(id) VALUES('{}')".format(message.from_user.id))
```

Comment: Используйте биндинг параметров, вместо ручного составления запросов: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table(id) VALUES(?)", [message.from_user.id])`

Comment: не до конца понял схему если не сложно можете пожалуйста представить весь код с чат ботом

Comment: @kiber мне нужно больше деталей. Обратись по юзернейму painstyle01 в телеграмме.